Find the sum of numbers in a column (SQL)
Define the following table:
CREATE TABLE Raw 
(
    PolicyNumber varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    [Plan Code] varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    CoverageNumber int NOT NULL,
    [Coverage Issue Date] date NOT NULL,
    IssueAge int NOT NULL,
    InsuredDOB date NOT NULL,
    TotalFace float NOT NULL,
    [Termination Date] date NOT NULL,
    TerminationReason varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    Gender varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    SmokerStatus varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    AnnualizedPremium float NOT NULL,
    Crcy varchar(10) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO [Raw] 
VALUES
('3332808787','S20QA',1,CONVERT(date,'19990608',112),19,CONVERT(date,'19790807',112),20000,CONVERT(date,'20110107',112),'B','F','0',732,'90'),
('3157139132','S20QA',1,CONVERT(date,'19990609',112),33,CONVERT(date,'19650720',112),50000,CONVERT(date,'20060207',112),'B','F','0',2376,'90'),
('1622449413','S20QA',1,CONVERT(date,'19990408',112),21,CONVERT(date,'19770409',112),20000,CONVERT(date,'20070707',112),'B','F','0',756,'90'),
('1966749563','S20QA',1,CONVERT(date,'19990609',112),30,CONVERT(date,'19681008',112),100000,CONVERT(date,'20060907',112),'B','F','0',4488,'90'),
('4239149716','S30QA',1,CONVERT(date,'19990727',112),19,CONVERT(date,'19791206',112),10000,CONVERT(date,'20070225',112),'B','F','0',456,'90'),
('1532109564','025QA',1,CONVERT(date,'19990727',112),26,CONVERT(date,'19720808',112),10000,CONVERT(date,'20131226',112),'B','F','0',540,'90'),
('1737229652','025QA',1,CONVERT(date,'19990609',112),30,CONVERT(date,'19680610',112),10000,CONVERT(date,'20110310',112),'B','F','0',564,'90'),
('3613176106','S30QA',1,CONVERT(date,'19990917',112),21,CONVERT(date,'19771202',112),30000,CONVERT(date,'20060816',112),'B','F','0',1380,'90'),
('2812726759','S30QA',1,CONVERT(date,'19990924',112),21,CONVERT(date,'19780406',112),10000,CONVERT(date,'20120523',112),'B','F','0',442,'90'),
('1613214958','S20QA',1,CONVERT(date,'19990926',112),28,CONVERT(date,'19701229',112),10000,CONVERT(date,'20090825',112),'B','F','0',672,'90'),
('4124180592','D01DE',1,CONVERT(date,'20041105',112),28,CONVERT(date,'19760106',112),70000,CONVERT(date,'20161231',112),'1','F','0',506,'90'),
('2783562258','D01DE',1,CONVERT(date,'20041109',112),33,CONVERT(date,'19711020',112),50000,CONVERT(date,'20161231',112),'1','F','0',531,'90'),
('3641040493','D01DE',1,CONVERT(date,'20050606',112),45,CONVERT(date,'19600507',112),20000,CONVERT(date,'20150115',112),'D','F','0',480,'90'),
('2289932527','D01DE',1,CONVERT(date,'20010819',112),49,CONVERT(date,'19560520',112),40000,CONVERT(date,'20161231',112),'1','M','1',1990,'90'),
('3601742355','D01DE',1,CONVERT(date,'20030301',112),33,CONVERT(date,'19701002',112),50000,CONVERT(date,'20161231',112),'1','F','0',578,'90'),
('1830607130','D01DE',1,CONVERT(date,'20041218',112),31,CONVERT(date,'19741021',112),100000,CONVERT(date,'20150910',112),'B','F','0',854,'90'),
('2352605305','D01DE',1,CONVERT(date,'20020122',112),43,CONVERT(date,'19631210',112),50000,CONVERT(date,'20161231',112),'1','M','0',1555,'90'),
('2587270075','D01DE',1,CONVERT(date,'20040925',112),31,CONVERT(date,'19730321',112),20000,CONVERT(date,'20161231',112),'D','F','0',190,'90'),
('3733814516','D01DE',2,CONVERT(date,'20000925',112),32,CONVERT(date,'19730321',112),80000,CONVERT(date,'20160501',112),'B','F','0',758,'90'),
('1429938264','D01DE',1,CONVERT(date,'20011006',112),35,CONVERT(date,'19681107',112),20000,CONVERT(date,'20161231',112),'1','M','1',384,'90'),
('2041540074','025QA',1,CONVERT(date,'19990903',112),31,CONVERT(date,'19680116',112),10000,CONVERT(date,'20140218',112),'D','F','0',560,'90'),
('4287465979','020QA',1,CONVERT(date,'19990906',112),38,CONVERT(date,'19601025',112),20000,CONVERT(date,'20140222',112),'D','F','0',1344,'90'),
('1760875076','010QA',1,CONVERT(date,'20000327',112),48,CONVERT(date,'19510823',112),10000,CONVERT(date,'20070508',112),'D','F','0',1282,'90'),
('2433672739','S15VA',1,CONVERT(date,'20010305',112),36,CONVERT(date,'19641224',112),50000,CONVERT(date,'20110305',112),'D','F','0',3209,'90'),
('2821715890','020VA',1,CONVERT(date,'20011015',112),36,CONVERT(date,'19650526',112),10000,CONVERT(date,'20060507',112),'D','F','0',502,'90'),
('4056174634','010VA',1,CONVERT(date,'20011108',112),47,CONVERT(date,'19540731',112),10000,CONVERT(date,'20110720',112),'D','F','0',1006,'90'),
('4041953932','025VA',1,CONVERT(date,'20011230',112),31,CONVERT(date,'19701027',112),30000,CONVERT(date,'20090126',112),'D','F','0',1171,'90'),
('3929249579','D01VA',1,CONVERT(date,'20030621',112),55,CONVERT(date,'19480409',112),50000,CONVERT(date,'20151129',112),'D','F','0',2315,'90'),
('1473591771','D01VA',1,CONVERT(date,'20031027',112),22,CONVERT(date,'19810125',112),10000,CONVERT(date,'20110728',112),'D','M','0',36,'90'),
('3828362177','D01VA',1,CONVERT(date,'20030529',112),34,CONVERT(date,'19690312',112),50000,CONVERT(date,'20060622',112),'D','M','0',312,'90'),
('2030800439','D01VA',1,CONVERT(date,'20050518',112),29,CONVERT(date,'19750819',112),50000,CONVERT(date,'20130806',112),'B','F','0',311,'90'),
('1060719809','D01VA',1,CONVERT(date,'20031028',112),50,CONVERT(date,'19530324',112),10000,CONVERT(date,'20151202',112),'D','M','0',639,'90'),
('1688681321','010JR',1,CONVERT(date,'19990609',112),48,CONVERT(date,'19501216',112),10000,CONVERT(date,'20061206',112),'B','F','0',901,'90'),
('1963302451','030JR',1,CONVERT(date,'19990609',112),28,CONVERT(date,'19710126',112),20000,CONVERT(date,'20120823',112),'D','F','0',625,'90'),
('2973264800','S20JR',1,CONVERT(date,'19990610',112),25,CONVERT(date,'19731115',112),50000,CONVERT(date,'20150414',112),'B','F','0',1885,'90')

I want to find out how many plan codes that contain the string 01 there are but I just couldn't figure out how to add the numbers in the column.
Here's the code that I came up with:
SELECT [Plan Code], COUNT(*) AS 'How Many' 
FROM Raw 
WHERE [Plan Code] LIKE '%01%' 
GROUP BY [Plan Code];

and it outputs



Plan Code
How Many




010JR
1


010QA
1


010VA
1


D01DE
10


D01VA
5



All that's left to do is add the numbers in the column (which sums up to 18) but I can't translate it into code. Any thoughts on how to proceed?

The [] are not valid when using mysql. Please tag the database you are REALLY using (see this test: https://dbfiddle.uk/JXU9Pp1Z )

I'm new to SQL and my instructor told me to use SQL Fiddle

For the final sum, you can use your SQL as a subquery, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/wYOUUS3d

What does the small x do?

The x is an alias for the result of the subquery, like [How Many] is an alias for the count(*)

So it refers to 'FinalSum'?

No, FinalSum is a column in the table (or result) with the name x.

Hasn't your instructor told you about brackets and quotes? In standard SQL, and most database management systems (DBMS) for that matter, we use single quotes for string literals (like in LIKE '%01%') and double quotes for names that contain special characters (AS "How Many"). There exist DBMS, though, that have a syntax different from the standard and use the brackets for names instead (AS [How Many]). Anyway, names with special characters like blanks should be avoided in the first place, so no quotes are needed (e.g. AS how_many).

Just drop the GROUP BY clause and [Plan Code] column from your query. It works. tested on my machine.
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'How Many' 
FROM Raw 
WHERE [Plan Code] LIKE '%01%' 

Thank you.

Or, when individual subtotals are also needed, you can use WITH ROLLUP
